# How do I refactor modals that operate on different DIVs to be DRY?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have about 9 small javascript functions on my page that all do the same thing, open up a modal for the content inside the div where the button is located.

The only difference between them all is that each one references a different div. I'd like to refactor this code so that I'm not repeating any code that does the modal operation.

[Here is the codepen](http://codepen.io/MarkBond/pen/jPpwOJ?editors=100):

Javascript:

```
// FINDS THE MODAL AND THEN PLACES THE IBOX CONTENT THAT IS CURRENTLY
// ACTIVE INSIDE THE MODAL'S BODY

$('[data-target="#enlargeElementModal"]').on('click', function () {
    $('#enlargeElementModal .modal-body').html($('#ibox-1 .content.active').html());
});

$('[data-target="#enlargeStrategyModal"]').on('click', function () {
    $('#enlargeStrategyModal .modal-body').html($('#ibox-2 .content.active').html());
});

....and many more of these
```

Some HTML:

```html
// IMPORTANT PART OF ENLARGE MODAL
<div class="modal modal-wide fade" id="enlargeElementModal" role="dialog"><!--ENLARGE SCREEN MODAL-->
      <div class="modal-dialog">
             <div class="modal-content">
                     <div class="modal-header">
                           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                           </button>
                           <h4 class="modal-title">Element Map</h4>
                     </div>
             <div class="modal-body">
                  <p></p>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-footer">
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
             </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>


// IMPORTANT PART OF IBOX-CONTENT
<div class="ibox-content mapStyle" id="ibox-1"><!--CONTENT INSIDE THE DIV BODY-->
                <div class="active content" id="elementMap"><!--MAP CONTENT-->
                ....content
                </div>
</div>
```

How do I refactor the modal JavaScript so I don't repeat code?

Comment: I would go for this

    var myFunc = function (myDiv) {
        $('#enlargeElementModal .modal-body').html($(myDiv + ' .content.active').html()
    
    $('[data-target="#enlargeElementModal"]').on('click', function () {
       return myFunc("#ibox-1");
    } );
    });
    
    $('[data-target="#enlargeElementModal"]').on('click', function () {
       return myFunc("#ibox-2");
    } );
    });

Comment: @GeorgeStocker - If this is off topic then so are most of the JS questions on SO. For starters OP was not asking why its not working, they were asking specifically how to redo the code to remove repitition. That's clear, answerable and is relevant to other people. A duplicate I could buy, but off-topic, not at all.

Comment: @Jamiec The problem with your question is (as the off topic reason states) that we're missing information we need: a clear problem statement "need help making JavaScript dynamic" is not a clear problem statement; including the actual problem you face; as well as some cleanup of your question (we don't need the meta commentary). If you're just asking for a refactoring, then your best bet is to go to codereview.stackexchange.com, a site made for these things.

Comment: @Jamiec - thats exactly what i was thinking. My code works totally fine, I just need some help on making it less redundant :/

Comment: @GeorgeStocker oh come on! Anyone who knows javascript knows exactly what this user was asking! User has even expressed they are not experienced, so they do not know the right terminology to use. In addition - its not my question (helps if you actually read something before casting your vote!!)

Comment: @Jamiec It's not just for the users stumbling across the page because it's on the front page or in their tags; it's for the users coming from Google. We have a bit of a higher standard here for the composition of questions, [and for good reason](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299411/16587).

Comment: @George, please dont preach to me about how to use SO. I know full well. You made a bad decision here, its fine we all make them. The question is why you've not rectified it.

Comment: @Jamiec By rectify it, do you mean explain why it was closed; edit it; and then re-open it? That was done [2 minutes before you wrote that comment](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31477706/revisions). You could have also done the same thing, given that you have (as of this writing) 46.7K reputation.  Instead of complaining about moderation, you could have fixed the question. The question becomes, why didn't you?

Comment: @Jamiec - Thanks for standing up for me, but its all good now so no need to sweat over it :)

Comment: @GeorgeStocker except a pointless sentence with a "lol" I saw nothing wrong with the question as it stood. I was busy *answering* it. I also cast my reopen vote. Not sure what more I *could* have done. Dealing with new users takes a little more "kid gloves" than I believe you exercised. Im also a SE mod, so I feel your pain, I dont mean to have a go at you. But in this instance I believe you were too hasty with your close hammer.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker - what does DRY stand for ?

Comment: @Markus - [Dont Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). It's a common acronym used in programming which essentially means write things in such a way as they are reusable, and do not need to be copy/pasted with small changes

Comment: @Jamiec - ahhh ok makes sense, thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add another `data-*` attribute onto each button to indicate where the content comes from:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-toggle="modal"
     data-target="#enlargeStrategyModal" data-content="#ibox-2">
```

And then use this same code to activate every button:

```
$('[data-target]').on('click',function(){
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    var content = $(this).data('content');
    $(target + ' .modal-body').html($(content + ' .content.active').html());
  });
```

Live example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dojRRZ

Comment: Thank you so much Jamiec, made it very simple, and thanks again for standing up for me :D